# Const static set of reference to const static maps

Tags: c++, reference, static, set, constants

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <initializer_list>

typedef std::map<std::string, bool> M1;
typedef std::set<int, const M1&> S1;

const static M1 m_1 = {{"USA", 0}, {"Africa", 1}, {"Netherlands", 0}};
const static M1 m_2 = {{"apple", 1}, {"oranges", 0}, {"pineapple", 0}};
const static M1 m_3 = {{"desk", 0}, {"chair", 1}, {"lamp", 0}};

const static S1 s_1 = {{33, &m_1}, {42, &m_2}, {77, &m_3}};

int main() { return (0); }
```

When I try to compile this piece of code I get just 1 error for the initialization of the `set`, and I have no idea about why my compiler behaves like that ( both clang 3.4 and gcc 4.8.1 ) since it's a simple `set` of `int` and `constant references` to a `map` and that's what I'm feeding to the constructor.

What I'm missing here ?

Comment: @Borgleader what ? can you expand a little more ?

Comment: You're feeding pointers to s_1. (disregard previous comment, i missed the typedef) &m_1 is not a reference to to a map, its a an M1*

Comment: Why are you passing two template parameters to set? It doesn't store a pair.

Comment: @NeilKirk it gives the same error with std::map too, it's not a problem about using std::set for what I have tried ...

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't, I'm just saying set is definately wrong and asking about your reason behind the parameters as it doesn't make sense. Unless sets work differently in C++11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template of class set is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/?kw=set

```
template < class T,                        // set::key_type/value_type
           class Compare = less<T>,        // set::key_compare/value_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<T> >    // set::allocator_type
           > class set;
```

So when you say

```
typedef std::set<int, const M1&> S1;
```

you are using M1& as the comparing criteria, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

- You're giving pointers instead of references in your map
  declarations
- Either you make S1 a map or you only pass one    parameter to the
  template

With maps this compiles (Qt Creator 5.1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <initializer_list>

typedef std::map<std::string, bool> M1;
typedef std::map<int, const M1&> S1;
typedef std::set<M1> S2;

const static M1 m_1 = {{"USA", false}, {"Africa", true}, {"Netherlands", false}};
const static M1 m_2 = {{"apple", true}, {"oranges", false}, {"pineapple", false}};
const static M1 m_3 = {{"desk", false}, {"chair", true}, {"lamp", false}};

const static S1 s_1 = {{33, m_1}, {42, m_2}, {77, m_3}};
const static S2 s_2 = {m_1, m_2, m_3};

int main() { return (0); }
```

EDIT: Added a typedef S2 for `std::set`